# Addition of differentiable function on regular surface is still differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, surfaces

Given two differentiable functions $f,g:V\to \mathbb{R}^n$ where $V\subset S$ is open subset of regular surface $S$.

Prove that $f+g$ with $(f+g)(x) = f(x)+ g(x)$ is still differentiable.

My attempt:for a given $x\in V$,we need to show $f+g$ is differentiable at this point,to do this we need to find one chart map $z:W\to \mathbb{R}^n$,such that $(f+g)z$ is differentiable, we have already have two different chart $a:U\to \mathbb{R}^n$ and $b:V\to \mathbb{R}^n$,such that $fa$ and $gb$ is differentiable function from $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^n$.My question is how to construct such $z$,based on $a,b$.

Comment: This might be helpful https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1406750/differential-geometry-restriction-of-differentiable-map-to-regular-surface-is-d

Comment: It would help to state that $f$ and $g$ are differentiable, in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: While in the definition only existence of one chart map is required, one usually proves next, that compositions of differentiabele functions with arbitrary chart maps is differentiable.

Comment: Do you mean for chart $b$ there is a reparameterization map $h = b^{-1}a$ that makes $ga$ is differentiable,so we have $fa$ and $ga$ differentiable so such $z = a$ satify the condition?

Comment: This is partly repeating the proof of the fact that I want to use. The fact you have is that for a differentialable map $f$, the composition with any chart map is smooth whereever it is defined.